# Error in iterator while implementing doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, linked-list, abstract-class

I am getting an ambiguous error in which I am trying to implement the iterator of a link list class. The program says that the function is not a part of my class, when it is.

Tester program:

```
for(list<int>::iterator it = l3.begin() ; it!=l3.end(); ++it)
        cout<<(int)(it.value())<<" ";
```

Link List Class:

```
template<typename T>
class list
{
    int len;
    link<T>* head, tail;
    public:
        /*class functions*/

        class iterator{
            link<T>* ptr;
            public:
                iterator() {ptr = nullptr;}
                iterator(link<T>* p) {ptr = p;}
                link<T>* get_ptr(){return ptr;}
                iterator(iterator a){ptr = a.get_ptr();}
                ~iterator(){delete[] ptr;}
                T& value(){return ptr->get_val();}
                void operator=(iterator iter){ptr = iter.get_ptr();}
                bool operator==(iterator iter){return ptr == iter.get_ptr();}
                void operator++(){ptr = ptr->get_next();}
                void operator--(){ptr = ptr->get_prev();}
                bool operator!=(iterator iter){return ptr != iter.get_ptr();}  
        };
        iterator begin(){return iterator(head);}
        iterator end(){return iterator(nullptr);};
};
```

Error:

```
listtest.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
listtest.cpp:24:19: error: ‘class mod::list<int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘value’
cout<<(int)(it.value())<<" ";
```

I have commented the definitions of all the functions of the `list` class, but still am getting the same error. This is my `link` class, which acts as node to the `list` class.

```
template<typename T>
class list;

template<typename T>
class link{
    template<typename U>
        friend class list;
    private:
        T value;
        link<T>* prev; 
        link<T>* next;
    public:
        link(){prev = next = nullptr;}
        link(const T& val){value = val; prev = next = nullptr;}
        T& get_val(){return value;}
        link<T>* get_prev(){return prev;}
        link<T>* get_next(){return next;}           
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Clang says something like `error: invalid constructor; you probably meant 'list<T>::iterator (const list<T>::iterator&)' instead of iterator(iterator a){ptr = a.get_ptr();}`. You then get issues with `const` correctness. After fixing that I get a segfault because when creating a `list<int>` `head` is never initialized and points to invalid data. After you fix those errors it will probably become apparent what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in one of the ctors for the iterator:

```
 iterator(iterator a) { ptr = a.get_ptr(); }
```

It should be:

```
iterator(iterator& a) { ptr = a.get_ptr(); }
```